# Call external function from Webmethod

Tags: vb.net

I've an issue to fix with my program.
I send data from frontend to my vb.net backend with ajax to a Webmethod function.
The problem is that i can't call another external function because this method in "Shared". How can i fix this?

I used this Webmethod to get two paraters from frontend. Then i moved and renamed two files chaining these together. Now: how can i download them in frontend assuming that i've them path?

```
<WebMethod()> 'PRENDE I DATI DEL FORNITORE E PROCEDE AL DOWNLOAD DEI FILE
Public Shared Function CompilaModuli(ByVal nomeFrn As String, ByVal pIVA As String) As String
    HttpContext.Current.Session(“nomeForn”) = nomeFrn
    HttpContext.Current.Session(“pIVA”) = pIVA
    Dim rtnStr As String = "Campi completati correttamente, a breve inizierà il download."

    Dim modulesDirectory As String = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("PATH_AUTOVAL_SAMPLE")) 'CARTELLA AUTOVALUTAZIONI SAMPLE
    Dim ausDirectory As String = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("PATH_AUTOVAL_AUS")) 'CARTELLA AUTOVALUTAZIONI AUS
    Dim finalName As String = nomeFrn + "_" + pIVA

    'COPIO I FILE ORIGINALI E LI RINOMINO CON NOMEFORNITORE, PIVA E NOME FILE ORIGINALE NELLA CARTELLA /AUS
    Try
        For Each FILE As String In Directory.GetFiles(modulesDirectory)
            Debug.WriteLine("---DEBUG--- FILE ORGINALE>_ " + FILE)
            IO.File.Copy(FILE, String.Concat(ausDirectory, finalName + "-" + IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(FILE)) & ".pdf")
            Debug.WriteLine("---DEBUG--- FILE COPIATI>_ " + String.Concat(ausDirectory, finalName) & ".pdf")
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return "Qualcosa è andato storto, riprovare per favore."
    End Try
    Return rtnStr
End Function
```

Comment: *"The problem is that i can't call another external function because this method in "Shared""*. Huh? Maybe I'm missing something but that seems like a non sequitur to me.

Comment: @jmcilhinney This method is shared, so it cannot call other, non-shared methods of the same class. The solution to which is to remove the `shared`.

Comment: @GSerg, facts not in evidence your honour. That's a likely explanation but we shouldn't have to make assumptions.

Comment: Also the second part of the question doesn't seem to have much to do with the first part. It's not clear which is the main issue really, or whether they are just entirely separate problems.